# Pandas DataFrame, how get data elements without dtype and \nName

Tags: python, string, pandas

I uploaded a pandas dataframe with

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv("names.csv", header=None)
```

this dataframe contains names and surnames of people. Its size is `(38,1)`. Anyway, when I tried to get the first name,

```
str(data.loc[1])
```

(I need a string) I obtain:

```
'0    John Smith\nName: 1, dtype: object'
```

Why? I would like to have:

```
'John Smith'
```

Comment: did the solution work for you ? if yes pls accept :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the output you are getting is: 'data.loc[1]' is a pandas.core.series.Series object. When you convert it to str, the whole series with all its details gets converted to a string object.

This should give what you are looking for.

```
data.loc[1].values[0]
```

or

```
data.loc[1].tolist()[0]
```

or

```
data.loc[1,0]
```

The type of o/p is string - you may not have to convert it to string type further.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `csv` contains a single column, use the `squeeze` argument of `pd.read_csv`. This will return a `Series`, which now allows you to select an individual value with `.loc` as Series are 1-D.

---

#### Sample Data: `names.csv`

```
foo
bar
bazz
boo
John Smith
```

---

#### Code

```
s = pd.read_csv('names.csv', header=None, squeeze=True)
s.loc[4]
#'John Smith'
```